# CMD Fileless equivalent of < redirection

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, cisco-anyconnect

I have a batch that wraps AnyConnect Mobility Client CLI (vpncli.exe) and asks username and password to later handle them to vpncli.

Simplified code:

```
set /p user_id=Username:
set /p pwd=Password:
echo %user_id%> c:\temp\configvpn.txt
echo %pwd%>> c:\temp\configvpn.txt

set install_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"

%install_dir%\vpncli.exe connect myvpn.mydomain.TLD -s < c:\temp\configvpn.txt

net use h: \\fileserver\sharename /user:domain\%user_id% %pwd%
```

The last line it's why we do it this way: to not prompt user password twice (first for connecting VPN and second to map network drive)

For security reasons I'm improving the script to not write password to disk. **I need a fileless equivalent of this "< c:\temp\configvpn.txt"**

I tried :

```
(
    @echo %user_id%
    @echo %pwd% 
) | %install_dir%\vpncli.exe connect myvpn.mydomain.TLD -s
```

Not success so far. The output is this loop:

```
  >> Please enter your username and password.
Group: VPN-TESTGROUP

Username: [myUsername] Password:
  >> Login failed.
Group: VPN-TESTGROUP

Username: [myUsername] Password:
  >> Login failed.
```

(repeats indefinitely)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It seems vpncli.exe supports giving the username and password as parameters. See https://docstore.mik.ua/univercd/cc/td/doc/product/vpn/client/3_6/admin_gd/vcach4.htm

Comment: so: `vpncli connect myvpn.mydomain.tld user MyUser pwd MyPass`

Comment: Actually no. This is old documentation of legacy VPN Client. I tried myself but current vpncli (referring anyconnect 4.6) throws an error using this syntax. Thanks anyway

Comment: Question was asked and answered on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729649/cmd-fileless-equivalent-of-redirection)